# Is there any average time span estimate for change in a "perception"?

Tags: perception, time

This question is about a perception in general and not related to a specific perception.

Suppose an individual has a perception (say X) on a particular phenomenon and later, the individual came to know that her perception is wrong and found the correct perception (say Y) on that phenomenon.

How much time, in general, it takes for the individual to get stabilisation in the new perception?

Or does the transition strongly depends on the individual, environment and phenomenon under consideration so that it is impossible to find the average estimate?

Comment: Perception **in general** can be considered subjective to a degree and therefore it will depend on a number of factors including the reason for the person perceiving the "wrong" thing. They could be correct and others are wrong. This question is very broad in the sense that perception as a subject involves many different ways people perceive things. Can you narrow your question down to a particular form of perception and still obtain the same kind of answer you are after?

Comment: Okay then, I will try to narrow down @ChrisRogers